# Error in data.table about the columns to join by must be specified using 'on=' argument

Tags: r, data.table

I write a function for extract row based on condition like below :

```
ex <- function(x, y){
  Sname <- paste0("A00-",x)
  state <- paste0(x, "_state")
  test1 <- paste0(x, "_test1")
  test2 <- paste0(x, "_test2")
  temp <- dt[c("ID",state,test1,test2)
  temp[,test1] <- ifelse(temp[,state] >= y, temp[,test1] ,"NA")
  head(temp)]
  }
```

And my table has columns

```
> names(dt)
 [1] "ID"            "A_test1"       "A_test2"       "A_state"     "A_anoo"     
 [6] "B_test1"       "B_test2"       "B_state"       "B_anoo"      "C_test1"      
[11] "C_test2"       "C_state"       "C_anoo"
```

When I use my function`ex(x = "B", y= 0.2)` ,I will got this error :

```
>   temp <- dt[c("ID",state,test1,test2)]
Error in `[.data.table`(dt, c("ID",state,test1,test2), ) : 
  When i is a data.table (or character vector), the columns to join by must be specified using 'on=' argument (see ?data.table), by keying x (i.e. sorted, and, marked as sorted, see ?setkey), or by sharing column names between x and i (i.e., a natural join). Keyed joins might have further speed benefits on very large data due to x being sorted in RAM.
```

If someone could help me out it'd be great.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is related to non-standard evaluation within data.table.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(iris)
cols <- c("Species", "Sepal.Length")
DT[cols]
#Error in `[.data.table`(DT, cols) : 
#  When i is a data.table (or character vector), the columns to join by must be specified using 'on=' argument (see ?data.table), by keying x (i.e. sorted, and, marked as sorted, see ?setkey), or by sharing column names between x and i (i.e., a natural join). Keyed joins might have further speed benefits on very large data due to x being sorted in RAM.

DT[, .SD, .SDcols = cols]
#       Species Sepal.Length
#  1:    setosa          5.1
#  2:    setosa          4.9
#  3:    setosa          4.7
#  4:    setosa          4.6
#  5:    setosa          5.0
# ---                       
#146: virginica          6.7
#147: virginica          6.3
#148: virginica          6.5
#149: virginica          6.2
#150: virginica          5.9
```

I also suggest you study the data.table vignettes and documentation, in particular regarding `:=` (assignment by reference) and `fifelse`. Mixing data.table and base R (sub-)assignments should be avoided.

Comment: ,thank for reply, I fix the fist error at ```temp <- dt[c("ID",state,test1,test2)```, but still can't fix ifelse in my code. temp[, test1:= ifelse(state>= y, test1, "NA")] ,could you give my some hint?

Comment: Probably something like `temp[, (test1) := fifelse(get(state)>= y, get(test1), NA)]`. I'm pretty sure everything would be easier for you if your reshaped your data.table to long format.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Still need study documentation again.